# Using Python subprocess and string formating

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I am attempting to call a windows command with relevant arguments using python's `subprocess` . The command is executing and the arguments and their values look to be correct, however It only seems to be working correctly when using the "local mode" `-l`.
I'm getting an `invalid argument/option` error when using the remote mode. Could any point out where im going wrong?

Could anyone point out how to format the `subprocess.check_ouput()` arguments correctly to include the variables given at commandline when executing the script? As you can see ive tryd using string formating, both old and new to try get it working as I cant workout how to add the last `domain` variable inbetween the filter (/FI) argument value without string formatting.

expected commandline to execute

```
tasklist /V /S 192.168.1.122 /U 'DOMAIN'\'USERNAME' /P 'PASSWORD' /FI "USERNAME eq 'DOMAIN'\*"
```

with this commandline example of the script:

```
hunter.py -d DOMAIN -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -s servers.txt
```

This is the **error:**

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/S 192.168.1.122'.
Type "TASKLIST /?" for usage.
```

Clearly the argument is correct "visually" correct anyway, here is the usage for the tasklist:

```
Description:
This tool displays a list of currently running processes on
either a local or remote machine.

Parameter List:
/S     system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

/U     [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which
                       the command should execute.

/P     [password]       Specifies the password for the given
                       user context. Prompts for input if omitted.

/M     [module]         Lists all tasks currently using the given
                        exe/dll name. If the module name is not
                        specified all loaded modules are displayed.

/SVC                    Displays services hosted in each process.

/APPS                   Displays Store Apps and their accociated processes.

/V                      Displays verbose task information.

/FI    filter           Displays a set of tasks that match a
                        given criteria specified by the filter.

/FO    format           Specifies the output format.
                        Valid values: "TABLE", "LIST", "CSV".

/NH                     Specifies that the "Column Header" should
                        not be displayed in the output.
                        Valid only for "TABLE" and "CSV" formats.
/?                      Displays this help message.
```

This is the python **code** i have so far;

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Used for checking users logged into a list of servers.

Usage:
  hunter.py [-u <username>] [-p <password>] [-s <FILE>] (-d <domain>)
  hunter.py (-d <domain>) (-l)
  hunter.py -h | --help
  hunter.py --version

Options:
  -l --local
  -u --username
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  -p --password
  -d --domain
  -s --serverfile=FILE
  """
from docopt import docopt
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError

def tldomain(serverlist, domain, username, password):
    nlist = serverlist
    for serverl in nlist:
        try:
            print subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/S " + serverl, "/U" + domain, "\\" + username, "/P" + password, "/FI", "'USERNAME eq %s\\\*'"]) % domain
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.returncode)

def tllocal(domain):
        try:
            cmd = 'tasklist /V /FI "USERNAME eq {0}\\*"' .format(domain)
            subprocess.call(cmd)
        except OSError as e:
            print e

def getservers(servers):
        slist = open(servers).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in slist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
    print arguments

    if (arguments['--local']) == False:
        serverlist = getservers(arguments['--serverfile'])
        tldomain(serverlist, arguments['<domain>'], arguments['<username>'], arguments['<password>'])

    else:
        tllocal(arguments['<domain>'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in your arguments as separate elements in the list and apply the string formatting to the last element, no the output of the `subprocess.check_output()` call:

```
print subprocess.check_output(
    ["tasklist", "/V", "/S", serverl, "/U", domain + "\\" + username,
     "/P", password, "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\\*" % domain])
```

Note that I also removed the `'` quoting from the last argument, leave that to the `subprocess` module.

This also assumes that `domain` is always a non-empty string; if that's not the case, use:

```
if domain:
    domain += '\\'

print subprocess.check_output(
    ["tasklist", "/V", "/S", serverl, "/U", domain + username,
     "/P", password, "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s*" % domain])
```

e.g. only use the `\` backslash when `domain` is actually specified.

Comment: arr you keep the formating inside the brackets. thank you Martijin Pieters. Ill apply the change now and get back to you.

Comment: thanks again Martijin for explaining how to format the arguments. Any clue to why im getting the above error when trying to execute tasklist command?

Comment: @user3449832: I've shown you that `/S` and `serverl` should be separate elements in the argument list; did you correct that too?

Comment: yes i did just as you did above. Is it good practice for me to post the newly altered code? replacing the old?

Comment: And the same message is still displayed?

Comment: Does the same command line work in a console (without Python)?

Comment: @martijin Pieters seems i didnt save the newly added code :), amd now receiving this instead `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '\DOMAIN'.
Type "TASKLIST /?" for usage.`

Comment: yes the commandline works natively. I think the way the arguments are formatted is presenting the problem.

Comment: the /U should be one argument. example /U DOMAIN\USER current code looks to be parsing the DOMAIN and USER as separate arguments

Comment: @user3449832: No, `domain + '\\' + username` builds *one* string element in the argument list.

Comment: @user3449832: is `domain` empty perhaps? Because in that case you generate `\username` only, and that's not a valid argument.

Comment: strange my arguments values are showing the wrong way around :$ `{'--domain': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--local': False,
 '--password': True, I will try work it out formyself quickly
 '--serverfile': 'servers.txt',
 '--username': True,
 '--version': False,
 '<domain>': 'pass',
 '<password>': 'user',
 '<username>': 'Domain'}`

Comment: Seems if I use the -d argument first on the commandline it becomes the username for some reason :$, i thought it should know how to assign values according to the usage policy

Comment: Have checked the values all have entries and still same problem. {'--domain': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--local': False,
 '--password': True,
 '--serverfile': 'servers.txt',
 '--username': True,
 '--version': False,
 '<domain>': 'domain',
 '<password>': 'pass',
 '<username>': 'user'}

Comment: @user3449832: I don't know `docopt`, sorry

Comment: Ok seems to be working as expected now, i changed it to `subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/S", serverl, "/U", domain + "\\" + username, "/P", password, "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\\*" % domain])`